# What's wrong with this dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

What's wrong with my dockerfile?
The dockerfile is in the rootfolder of my repo and the dist-folder too.

```
FROM nginx

# copy folder
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx"]
```

I build the image:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.nginx -t localhost:5000/test/image:${version} .
```

The image is there after performing `docker images`

It looks so simple but when I try to run the image as a container:

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 localhost:5000/test/image:15
545445f961f4ec22becc0688146f3c73a41504d65467020a3e572d136354e179
```

But: `Exited (0) About a minute ago`

The `docker logs` shows nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default `nginx` behaviour is run as a daemon. To prevent this run `nginx` with parameter `daemon off`.

```
CMD ["nginx", "daemon off"]
```

Comment: but I want it to run as a daemon. That's why I was using -d option.

Comment: docker run -d -p 80:8080 nginx works fine, but not with my own image

Comment: Because default nginx docker CMD is `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`. look at https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/a8b6da8425c4a41a5dedb1fb52e429232a55ad41/Dockerfile

Comment: Will take a look at it. I was looking here: https://github.com/dockerfile/nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: `echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: Docker run `CMD` command. If command exit, docker exit too. That's why last command in `CMD` chain must have a "infinite loop".

Comment: Please be aware the the https://github.com/dockerfile/nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile dockerfile is **not** the official repository. It's better to look at the https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/a8b6da8425c4a41a5dedb1fb52e429232a55ad41/Dockerfile repository, because that's what's used for the official images.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Nginx will fork into the background and -- as the original foreground process has terminated -- the Docker container will stop immediately. You can have a look at how the [original image's Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/a8b6da8425c4a41a5dedb1fb52e429232a55ad41/Dockerfile) handles this:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The flag `-g "daemon off;"` causes Nginx to not fork, but continue running in the foreground, instead. And **since you're already extending the official `nginx` image**, you can drop your `CMD` line altogether, as it will be inherited from the base image, anyway.

Comment: In fact, both the `EXPOSE` and `CMD` are not required. There's no reason to run nginx on a different (8080) port, because you can map the port on different ports on the host (`-p host-port:container-port`)